# Linux not allowing to download filename with spaces

Tags: php, linux, html

I am not able to download the file whose filename has spaces in between them. Is there anything that can be done to make this work?

**NOTE:** From Windows Server,I am able to download

**But from Linux Server I am not able to download**

**Ubuntu -Server** is what I am using

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.somewebsite.com/68805/41/Junior (6).pdf" download="Junior (6).pdf">Download</a>
```

> error: Failed-Server Problem

Comment: Use : `<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo urlencode('http://www.somewebsite.com/68805/41/Junior (6).pdf" download="Junior (6).pdf') ?>">Download</a>`

Comment: Use urlencode() when displaying the href value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.somewebsite.com/68805/41/Junior%20(6).pdf" download="Junior%20(6).pdf">Download</a>
```

Difference is the URL-encoded space.